# PHP Vars to JavaScript Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using [this](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer) package to pass variables to javascript in Laravel 5.2, but I get:

> all.js:56Uncaught ReferenceError: categories is not defined

In my controller I am trying to pass variables like this:

```
JavaScript::put([
  'categories' => $numberOfViewsByCategory[0],
  'categoryViews' => $numberOfViewsByCategory[1],
  'chains' => $numberOfViewsByChain[0],
  'chainViews' => $numberOfViewsByChain[1]
]);
```

I have set the path in the config file:

```
'bind_js_vars_to_this_view' => 'layouts.partials.foot',
```

And my partials.foot blade looks like this:

```
@section('foot')
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/zurb/zurb.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-filer/jquery-filer.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/editor/editor.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js">  </script>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/all.js') }}"></script>
@stop
```

But when I do console.log(categories) in my all.js file, I get the above mentioned error.

Comment: What do you see in your HTML? Search for the `categories` var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the documentation says:

> which view you want your new JavaScript variables **to be prepended
>   to.**

So I suppose that in your `layout.blade.php` you have something like `@yield('footer')` for the moment.

I would suggest editing your `foot.blade.php` like:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/zurb/zurb.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-filer/jquery-filer.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/editor/editor.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js">  </script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/all.js') }}"></script>
```

And in your layout, to replace the `@yield` by an `@include('partials.foot')`

Comment: No, I am using already in my app.blade.php @section('foot')
      @include('layouts.partials.foot')
    @show

Comment: Yes, you should delete the @section part, it is not meant to be here